# extract number from string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract number from string 'iama5559348number'. Answer should do non capturing and expected output is 5559348. I am trying by doing this way 
`print(re.search(r'([^(.*)]?[0-9]*)','iama5559348number'))`but I am getting only only first letter

Comment: @Simon yes, I included now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` that way:

```
x= re.findall(r'[0-9]+','iama5559348number')[0]
print(x)
```

or that:

```
x= re.findall(r'\d+','iama5559348number')[0]
print(x)
```

Comment: Can you answer by using non capturing group for the letters 'iama'

Comment: @AdityaMatturi: added one case else

Comment: `(?!:iama)\d+` but it doesn't need at all

Comment: yeah, but I wanted more practice on non capturing. Just figuring out how to do with it

Comment: `(?!:iama)\d+?(?=number)` or `(?!:iama)\d*?(?=number)` without +, or else `(?!:\D*)\d*?(?=\D*$)`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> print(re.search(r'([0-9]+)','iama5559348number').groups()[0])
'5559348'
```

or

```
>>> print(re.search(r'(\d+)','iama5559348number').groups()[0])
'5559348'
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but can you use non capturing group(?:) or [^ ] and also use '*' instead of '+' in the answer

Comment: Just dunno how to do it without capture